# Firebase Warning: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I have been working on a Firebase web application, and all of a sudden when accessing certain elements of the database, it has been throwing a series of exceptions when attempting to use Object.keys in order to create an array of keys to iterate over each object.

This exact function was working perfectly until now, and certain child elements of the database still proceed without any errors.

Below is the code where I have the problem along with the error thrown in Chrome. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

```
//reference to firebase database at Flags/Employee t
    var ref = database.ref('Flags/Employee');
    //Take a snapshot of all Green Flags stored and use as training data for knn
    ref.on('value', function(snapshot){
        //Array of flag objects
        var storedFlags = snapshot.val();

        //Array of hashcodes used to access flags
        var keys = Object.keys(storedFlags);

        //Loop through each flag stored in the database at Flags/Employee
        //Find the flags with the smallest distance to the current flag
        //Store in a heap for later access
        for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
            var currentLookup = storedFlags[keys[i]];
```

Here are the errors which happen when the Object.keys function is called:

```
firebase-storage.js:3476 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 't' in 2
at M (firebase-storage.js:3476)
at t.cr (firebase-storage.js:3476)
at e.onMessage (firebase-storage.js:3476)
at e.nt (firebase-storage.js:3476)
at e.handleIncomingFrame (firebase-storage.js:3476)
at WebSocket.mySock.onmessage (firebase-storage.js:3476)
M @ firebase-storage.js:3476
t.cr @ firebase-storage.js:3476
(anonymous) @ firebase-storage.js:3476
e.nt @ firebase-storage.js:3476
e.handleIncomingFrame @ firebase-storage.js:3476
mySock.onmessage @ firebase-storage.js:3476




VM2298:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at r (firebase-storage.js:3476)
    at e.nt (firebase-storage.js:3476)
    at e.handleIncomingFrame (firebase-storage.js:3476)
    at WebSocket.mySock.onmessage (firebase-storage.js:3476)
r @ firebase-storage.js:3476
e.nt @ firebase-storage.js:3476
e.handleIncomingFrame @ firebase-storage.js:3476
mySock.onmessage @ firebase-storage.js:3476
VM2299:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at r (firebase-storage.js:3476)
    at e.nt (firebase-storage.js:3476)
    at e.handleIncomingFrame (firebase-storage.js:3476)
    at WebSocket.mySock.onmessage (firebase-storage.js:3476)
r @ firebase-storage.js:3476
e.nt @ firebase-storage.js:3476
e.handleIncomingFrame @ firebase-storage.js:3476
mySock.onmessage @ firebase-storage.js:3476
recommendations.js:635 null



firebase-storage.js:3476 FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at file:///home/tyler/Desktop/My%20Websites/DistroRecommendations/recommendations.js:638:24
    at t (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js:324:64323)
    at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js:324:59730
    at z (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js:324:10438)
    at t.raise (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js:324:110130)
    at t.In (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js:324:109788)
    at t.raiseEventsForChangedPath (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js:324:109610)
    at Object.onComplete (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js:324:140458)
    at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js:324:129429 
R @ firebase-storage.js:3476
(anonymous) @ firebase-storage.js:3476
setTimeout (async)
z @ firebase-storage.js:3476
t.raise @ firebase-storage.js:3476
t.In @ firebase-storage.js:3476
t.raiseEventsForChangedPath @ firebase-storage.js:3476
(anonymous) @ firebase-storage.js:3476
(anonymous) @ firebase-storage.js:3476
e.vr @ firebase-storage.js:3476
t.vr @ firebase-storage.js:3476
t.cr @ firebase-storage.js:3476
(anonymous) @ firebase-storage.js:3476
e.nt @ firebase-storage.js:3476
e.handleIncomingFrame @ firebase-storage.js:3476
mySock.onmessage @ firebase-storage.js:3476




firebase-storage.js:3476 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at recommendations.js:638
    at t (firebase-storage.js:3476)
    at firebase-storage.js:3476
    at z (firebase-storage.js:3476)
    at t.raise (firebase-storage.js:3476)
    at t.In (firebase-storage.js:3476)
    at t.raiseEventsForChangedPath (firebase-storage.js:3476)
    at Object.onComplete (firebase-storage.js:3476)
    at firebase-storage.js:3476
```